# Why does checkinstall need sudo?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, checkinstall

On Ubuntu, IIRC, `checkinstall` only create a deb package from compiled binary files, and doesn't install them to some destination directories (say, some system directories).

But I always have to run `sudo checkinstall` even when I compiled the files in a home directory, otherwise some operations will not be permitted.

Why is that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `checkinstall` also runs `make install` and installs all the files too, by default.

Comment: Right. My mistake. How to create deb without install?

Answer (score 2):

`checkinstall` needs `sudo`, because by default it actually performs the installation as well. This is due to the default `/etc/checkinstallrc`, which contains:

```
# Install the package or just create it?
INSTALL=1
```

To prevent the installation, and just create the package, do:

```
checkinstall --install=no
```

Comment: Thanks. Does `checkinstall --install=no`  need sudo?

Comment: @Tim I think it shouldn't, but I don't have anything handy to test it on.